# Is it possible to replicate DB from GoDaddy to Database in AWS SQL Server RDS using DMS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, migration

We are trying to create a DR solution that can be hosted in AWS and DC on GoDaddy. The problem is, DB is co-hosted in Godaddy and so no replication agents can be installed in the DB let alone do any changes there.

My question: is AWS DMS agentless?

Can we migrate and then replicate and then sync the DB in GD and RDS through any means with AWS DMS?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is agentless. It will ask you the connection string of the source Database and ask you to select RDS Database to migrate.

You can go to the AWS youtube channel and watch the tutorials.

Comment: Yes, but how is the connection established between them?
As our DB in GD is private, i.e. co-hosted, will it be possible to establish communication between them??